# copy line from a txt file and replace it in another txt file at specific number line using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm relatively new to PowerShell. I would like to be able to copy a text line from a list file and paste it on another text file at specific number line.

I have the first step copy specific number line and need the second steppaste at specific number line:

```
Get-Content C:\Temp\Megateo\Hash.txt -TotalCount 121 | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1 > C:\Temp\Megateo\Monin.txt
```

Comment: You'll have to read in all of the file you want to update. You can't just write a specific line without rewriting the whole file, you can only add to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the title of your question and also the latest comment you wrote, you are actually looking for a way to **replace** a line, rather than **inserting** a new line.

Try

In real life you want to get the input from files:

```
# Get your replacement line from the first file
$replacementText = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\Megateo\Hash.txt' -TotalCount 121 | Select-Object -Skip 1 -First 1
# and read the file you want to update
$lines = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\Megateo\Monin.txt'
```

But for demo here I'm using:

```
$replacementText = "This is the new line"

$lines = @"
text text text text text text
text text text text text text
Replace this line with something NEW
text text text text text text
text text text text text text
"@ -split '\r?\n'
```

If you already know the line index to replace, simply do

```
$index = 2
if ($index -lt $lines.Count) {
    $lines[$index] = $replacementText
    # and write the updated file
    $lines | Set-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\Megateo\Monin.txt'
}
else {
    Write-Warning "'$index' exceeds the total number of lines ($($lines.Count))"
}
```

However, if you need to first **find** the index using a search string, you can either use the `.IndexOf()` method on the $lines array as in [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71026879/9898643), which is Case-Sensitive, or use the `.FindIndex()` like below to find the line case-insensitively.
Remember that both `.IndexOf()` and `.FindIndex()` can return a value of -1 if the string you're looking for is not found.

```
# make the FindIndex() array method look for the string case-insensitively
$predicate = [Predicate[String]]{param($s) $s -like 'replace this line*'}

# try and find the index of the line to replace. if not found, this returns -1
$index = [array]::FindIndex([string[]]$lines, $predicate)
if ($index -ge 0) {
    # now change the line at position $index with the replacement string
    $lines[$index] = $replacementText
    # and write the updated file
    $lines | Set-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\Megateo\Monin.txt'
}
else {
    Write-Warning "Could not find the requested line"
}
```

Comment: thank you very much Theo, that's what i needed

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide a bit more details on where (index) you want to insert the line from the other file, but to show you one way to approach the problem slicing the index of your content file. Let's say we have `test.txt` which looks like this:

```
text text text text text text
text text text text text text
insert line below here
text text text text text text
text text text text text text
```

And we want to insert `hello world!` below `insert line below here`, here is how you could do it:

```
$toInsert = 'hello world!'
$content = Get-Content ./test.txt
$index = $content.IndexOf('insert line below here')

$newContent = @(
    $content[0..$index++]
    $toInsert
    $content[$index..($content.Count - 1)]
)

$newContent | Out-File path/to/newfile....
```

Now if we inspect `$newContent`:

```
PS /> $newContent

text text text text text text
text text text text text text
insert line below here
hello world!
text text text text text text
text text text text text text
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Santiago, i need copy the 2  number line text from the source file, and paste or replace it at  4 number line on target file text

Comment: @JuanCamiloCometa in that case, using this same code, on `$toInsert = ..` use your `Get-Content` which you already have, and on `$index = ` put the number of the line where you want to insert (note that index starts from 0, not 1. Line 4 would be Index 3) the rest should be the same

Comment: thank you very much, done, one last question i see that when i change the source text line to replace in the same line that previously i paste it,  paste in in the next number line and not replace it, how can i force it to replace it?$toInsert = Get-Content C:\Temp\Megateo\Hash.txt -TotalCount 121 | Select-Object -Skip 2 -First 1
$content = Get-Content C:\Temp\Megateo\Monin.txt
$index = 24

$newContent = @(
    $content[0..$index++]
    $toInsert
    $content[$index..($content.Count - 1)]
)

$newContent | Out-File  C:\Temp\Megateo\Monin.txt